Docker build fails when calling RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
Updates:

Updating runc to (latest Dedian Bullseye-version) v1.0.0-rc93 did not help
Updating to latest docker version (27.3.1) did not help
Changing Dockerfile RUNline to individual imports (say pip install requests) did not help
Same error occurs at RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip  if I introduce this before any other RUNcommand
The issue is related to executing the "RUN" command. "RUN ls -l" causes the same error

Initial post
I want to run one of my python scripts in a docker container on a Debian 11 system. This far I came with my Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.12-slim

WORKDIR /usr/local/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY PythonScript.py ./
CMD ["python", "PythonScript.py --arg1 value1 --..."]

This simple Dockerfile fails to build:
docker build -t myApp .

ends with error:
> [4/5] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt:
#5 0.035 Incorrect Usage: flag provided but not defined: -keep
#5 0.035   
#5 0.035 NAME:
#5 0.035    runc run - create and run a container
#5 0.035 
#5 0.035 USAGE:
#5 0.035    runc run [command options] <container-id>
#5 0.035 
#5 0.035 Where "<container-id>" is your name for the instance of the container that you
#5 0.035 are starting. The name you provide for the container instance must be unique on
#5 0.035 your host.
#5 0.035 
#5 0.035 DESCRIPTION:
#5 0.035    The run command creates an instance of a container for a bundle. The bundle
#5 0.035 is a directory with a specification file named "config.json" and a root
#5 0.035 filesystem.
#5 0.035 
#5 0.035 The specification file includes an args parameter. The args parameter is used   
#5 0.035 to specify command(s) that get run when the container is started. To change    the
#5 0.035 command(s) that get executed on start, edit the args parameter of the spec. See
#5 0.035 "runc spec --help" for more explanation.
#5 0.035 
#5 0.035 OPTIONS:
#5 0.035    --bundle value, -b value  path to the root of the bundle directory, defaults to the current directory
#5 0.035    --console-socket value    path to an AF_UNIX socket which will receive a file descriptor referencing the master end of the console's pseudoterminal
#5 0.035    --detach, -d              detach from the container's process
#5 0.035    --pid-file value          specify the file to write the process id to
#5 0.035    --no-subreaper            disable the use of the subreaper used to reap reparented processes
#5 0.035    --no-pivot                do not use pivot root to jail process inside rootfs.  This should be used whenever the rootfs is on top of a ramdisk
#5 0.035    --no-new-keyring          do not create a new session keyring for the container.  This will cause the container to inherit the calling processes session key
#5 0.035    --preserve-fds value      Pass N additional file descriptors to the container (stdio + $LISTEN_FDS + N in total) (default: 0)
#5 0.035    
#5 0.036 flag provided but not defined: -keep
------
process "/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

As it seems, this has something to do with runc but I don't have a clue where and how.

From what I found in the web, it seems that this is an issue with the version of runc and docker. Still, I do not know how to fix this...

Please edit your post and add your requirements.txt file to it, so we have a chance at reproducing your issue.

@HansKilian Didn't work with individual pip install  either (see "Updates" above). The requirements.txt seems not to be the root cause

# Use the official slim image for a smaller footprint
FROM python:3.12-slim

# Set working directory for the application
WORKDIR /usr/local/app

# Copy requirements file and install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the main Python script to the working directory
COPY PythonScript.py .

# Run the Python script with command-line arguments as needed
CMD ["python", "PythonScript.py", "--arg1", "value1", "--arg2", "value2"]

I build this image without issues by providing stubs for requirements.txt and PythonScript.py
$ docker --version
Docker version 27.3.1, build ce12230

$ docker build -t my_app .
[+] Building 17.3s (10/10) FINISHED                              docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 575B                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.12-slim        0.4s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.12-slim@sha256:032c52613401895a  3.1s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:3.12-slim@sha256:032c52613401895a  0.0s
 => => sha256:0dd753b657c966f26a5151f899593efa1f2874d71fabced 250B / 250B  0.3s
 => => sha256:032c52613401895aa3d418a4c563d2d05f993bc3ecc 9.12kB / 9.12kB  0.0s
 => => sha256:311c6c7090a52874c9118ad17dc95cd7d030dd8ec13 1.75kB / 1.75kB  0.0s
 => => sha256:fd162521da09c903c4a095888014bc3ecfab6c6d284 5.32kB / 5.32kB  0.0s
 => => sha256:f281ad68d61216b3c73260807e28f1b53c4b5f3f9e4 3.51MB / 3.51MB  1.1s
 => => sha256:aa77a90b11d9467bf46de202798f3e67b1172caff 13.63MB / 13.63MB  2.3s
 => => extracting sha256:f281ad68d61216b3c73260807e28f1b53c4b5f3f9e4af49a  0.1s
 => => extracting sha256:aa77a90b11d9467bf46de202798f3e67b1172caff28f7a19  0.5s
 => => extracting sha256:0dd753b657c966f26a5151f899593efa1f2874d71fabcedf  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 72B                                           0.0s
 => [2/5] WORKDIR /usr/local/app                                           0.3s
 => [3/5] COPY requirements.txt .                                          0.1s
 => [4/5] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip &&     pip instal  12.6s
 => [5/5] COPY PythonScript.py .                                           0.1s 
 => exporting to image                                                     0.5s
 => => exporting layers                                                    0.5s
 => => writing image sha256:d0570e6168ea5858bcee587580d55b705fbdcf0d2fc88  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/my_app 

Investigate your requirements.txt for issues.

Build on Ubuntu 22.04

Nope, sorry. I copy-pasted your "RUN" code line but ran into the same issue. I tried as well to pip install --no-cache-dir requests instead of using requirements.txt. I tried as well to split your one "RUN" line into two. Then the same error occurs at pip install upgrade pip

I don't experience this error in my environment. Keeping in mind docker platform agnostic nature, the issue likely lays into your version of docker or how it had been installed. I would suggest to remove and reinstall docker -- first by using Docker version 27.3.1 and if everything is fine upgrade to the latest docker version

I found out that running my code in Apptainer is possible without larger hassle. I think I will abandon Docker for now...
